# Regex ignoring hyphens and double hyphens

Tags: regex, beyondcompare

I am trying to get beyond compare ignore a single "-" and double "--" hyphen. I am comparing two PDF documents where the original has a single hyphen and the edited copy replaced all the single hyphens with doubles. I want Beyond Compare to ignore that difference.

I have searched and found where people are able to ignore after either a char or digit (below), but these may be preceded with a space?

```
[0-9,-]+
```

Comment: Would love to help - could you give an exact example of a statement you're taking in as the input and what you want to match exactly from that?

Comment: Would you still be interested in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the replacement setting (Session->Session Settings)
[image]

To do this, you don't need a regex, the replacement is done only in one side.